# Type 'PageViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPageViewControllerDataSource'

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to use a UIPageViewController in my storyboard to create a set of sliding images, but I keep getting this error:

> Type 'PageViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPageViewControllerDataSource'

And I don't understand why.

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    //for scroll view
    lazy var subViewControllers:[UIViewController] = {
        return[
            UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Slide_1") as! ViewController_0,
            UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Slide_2") as! ViewController_1,
            UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Slide_3") as! ViewController_2
        ]
    }()

    //after viewcontroller
    func pageViewController(_pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex:Int = subViewControllers.index(of: viewController) ?? 0
        if (currentIndex >= subViewControllers.count - 1) {
            return nil
        }
        return subViewControllers[currentIndex + 1]
    }

    //before viewcontroller
    func pageViewController(_pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let currentIndex:Int = subViewControllers.index(of: viewController) ?? 0
        if (currentIndex <= 0) {
            return nil
        }
        return subViewControllers[currentIndex - 1]
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    //setting the initial view for the slider
        setViewControllers([subViewControllers[0]],direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    //making style a normal slide
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation
    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return subViewControllers.count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a space between the `_` and the `pageViewController` parameter in your two methods that are part of the protocol (before/after pages).

The underscore denotes that the method, when called, does not need a label for that parameter.

For example:

```
func setBlob(_ blob: Blob) -> Bool {
}
```

Would look like this when it's called:

```
let myBlob = Blob()
setBlob(myBlob)
```

If it didn't have the `_` there it would expect `setBlob(blob: blob)`. It's convenient to be able to change or ignore the parameter names for the sake of code cleanliness. But since you don't have a space between the parameter label and the actual parameter name, it thinks the parameter name is `_pageViewController`.

There should be a red icon on the same line where the error shows and you can click that to automatically fill in the missing methods so you can easily see what is missing / incorrect. Your class has to implement all the required methods of the protocol and follow the same method signatures or else you'll get this error.